# dataTable ajax URL not working in laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel, datatable

In my application using dataTable. In that ajax URL we are using. But while running, error message showing url not found kind. But it is there in route file. Why it showing like that?
My dataTable code is,

```
var oTable = $('.table').DataTable({
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
        },
        searching: false,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "{{ URL::to('loadfeedback') }}",
            "data": function (d) {
                d.from_date = $('#from_date').val();
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": null},
            {"data": "name"},
        ],
        'columnDefs': [
            {
                "searchable": false,
                "orderable": false,
                "targets": 0
            },
        ],
        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
            var index = iDisplayIndex + 1;
            $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html(index);
            return nRow;
        },
        'iDisplayLength': 25,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "order": [[0, 'desc']]
    });
```

In routes.php

```
Route::get('loadfeedback', 'HomeController@loadfeedback');
```

In Controller.php

```
 public function loadfeedback() {       
    $input = Input::all();
    return Admin::loadfeedback($input);
}
```

What's wrong on this? And also it's working fine in my local system. After hosting only this issue found. But only this url, others are working fine.

Please help me.

Comment: please provide controller method code

Comment: ok, my question is updated with controller method code